# Error with React Native 0.53RC using Expo Client version 2.3.0

Tags: react-native, expo

I got this error that says:

```
React Native version mismatch.

JavaScript version 0.50.3
Native Version 0.52.0
```

I have used Expo Client 2.3.0 on my Android mobile device. This attached screenshot shows the error:

[image: React Native version mismatch]

Regards

Answer (score 0):

React Native 0.53-rc is not a version that is supported by Expo and **you always need to match the versions of React Native's JS and native code.**

---

When you specify an Expo SDK version, that tells Expo which of its included versions of React Native to run. For example, Expo SDK 25 corresponds to React Native 0.52; a project that specifies `"sdkVersion": "25.0.0"` would make Expo load the native code for React Native 0.52.

**Important:** This also means you must use the JavaScript for React Native 0.52. The most reliable way to do this is to use the corresponding copy of React Native released by Expo, which often looks like:

```
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-25.0.0.tar.gz"
```